# Case assumption missing from tactic state in lean4

Tags: lean4, beginner

I'm trying to prove `a <= max(a, b)` by case. I have this:

```
example (a b : Nat) : a <= (max a b) := by
  cases decide (a <= b) with
  | true =>
    sorry
  | false =>
    sorry
```

When I put my cursor before the first `sorry`, I see the following tactic state:

> [image]

The thing that's confusing me is I don't see "decide (a <= b)" as one of the available terms anywhere in the state. I need that in order to complete the case. How do I get access to the case assumption in order to finish the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cases h : decide(a <= b) with`.  You can read more about it in the doc string for `cases`.

```
example (a b : Nat) : a <= (max a b) := by
  cases h : decide (a <= b) with
  | true =>
    sorry
    /-
    case true
    a b : Nat
    h : decide (a ≤ b) = true
    ⊢ a ≤ max a b
    -/
  | false =>
    sorry
```